# Passwords are vulnerable to hash collision attacks?

Tags: collision-resistance, md5

As stated in [this page](http://th.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/People/lucks/HashCollisions/) large documents hashed using md5 maybe vulnerable to collision attacks. My question is even passwords of 6-30 character are vulnerable to such hash collision attacks? If yes, is there any proof available online or any example of two password phrase giving same md5 hash? I googled but of no help!.
Any how I am not going to store password hashed using md5, just asked this question out of curiosity.

Comment: A hash of a short character password is vulnerable to a Pre-image Attack. I suppose a collision in the password (e.g. two users both using "password" for password) is more likely than finding two different passwords hashing to the same value.

Comment: For 6 or 7 character passwords, there's no point in worrying about hash collisions. Just guessing the password would be much easier.

Comment: A bit of clarification for someone who's native language isn't English. You use _even_ to denote inclusion with a bit of disbilief, not to say that the password is an even value, or it has an even number of bytes?

Comment: HenrickHellström and DavidSchwartz thanks for your comments. @rath I used 'even' as adverb, [read more](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/even#Adverb)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When it comes to passwords, the risk of collision attacks depends on several factors:

1. **Password Length**: Longer passwords are generally less susceptible to collision attacks because the search space for potential collisions is larger. A longer password typically results in a longer input to the hash function, making it more difficult (though not impossible) for attackers to find a collision.
2. **Entropy**: The entropy of a password refers to the measure of randomness or unpredictability. A password with high entropy is less likely to collide with another password. Randomly generated passwords with sufficient length and complexity are less vulnerable to collision attacks compared to passwords that are short or predictable.
3. **Salt**: In practice, passwords are often hashed with a salt, which is a random value added to the password before hashing. This salt prevents attackers from precomputing hashes for commonly used passwords. With a sufficiently long and random salt, the likelihood of a collision is further reduced.

While it's theoretically possible for two different passwords of any length to produce the same MD5 hash, finding such collisions becomes exponentially more difficult as the length and entropy of the passwords increase. However, for shorter passwords or passwords with low entropy, collision attacks are more feasible.

As for examples of MD5 collisions for short inputs like passwords, there are known demonstrations of MD5 collisions for specific input pairs, but these demonstrations often involve highly controlled conditions and significant computational resources. They're not typically practical for real-world attacks against passwords.

Comment: This answer seems to conflate "collision" in the sense of "two users having picked the same password" with "collision" in the sense of a hash collision - i.e. two distinct inputs producing the same hash digest. E.g. the first point only makes sense in the former meaning, whereas a hash collision will *require* a large enough search space. I'm certain SHA-256 is collision-free over all 8-bit sequences.

Comment: The chances that hashing my (insecure) password gives the same hash as hashing your (insecure but different) password are minimal. Even if your password is “password”. There is an excellent chance that someone finds your insecure password, but no chance they find a different password with the same hash.

Answer (score 7):

Data of more than a few dozen bytes can be vulnerable to MD5 collision attacks, but only (as far as is known) when an adversary can *inject* (choose) enough data of her choice in *both* the legitimate and forged version, which is feasible in some important scenarios, including certificate signing. There is evidence this was used by the [flame malware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flame_%28malware%29), and [plausible speculation](http://cr.yp.to/talks/2013.03.12/slides.pdf) that it went undetected for years.

**No, passwords are not  vulnerable to hash *collision* attacks in the standard use of a password hash**, where the hash is stored instead of the correct password and used to test a candidate password; that's because the adversary is assumed not to know the password, and can not inject material in both hashed messages; it is thus immaterial that in such a standard password hashing application, what's hashed is generally below the threshold where MD5 collisions are known to be feasible.

However, **hashed passwords can often be recovered when their hash is known**, by a different attack, specifically a brute-force (first) [pre-image attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack): e.g. an [MD5 rainbow table](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=MD5+rainbow+table) if the password was hashed using MD5 without [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29); or, even with salt, enumerating plausible passwords using a [password cracker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_cracking). To defend against these attacks, one should avoid a password hash getting known, and when that can't be insured with high confidence must use a good, purposely slowed password hash, such as [scrypt](http://www.tarsnap.com/scrypt.html) with salt and appropriate parameters. Improving password hashing is an [active research topic](https://password-hashing.net/).

Update: [CodeInChaos](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/180/codesinchaos) rightly points in a comment below that even in the standard use of a password hash, an adversary allowed to change password (and perhaps, knowing the salt) could use a password collision so as to select a password such that another password allows access, which she could use to discredit the system to some degree.

Update: [Ricky Demer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/991/ricky-demer) rightly points in comments below that in some Password Authenticated Key Agreement (PAKE) protocols, finding collision on messages involving two different possible passwords can give a useful advantage to the adversary: the ability to check these two passwords with a single query.

Comment: The adversary can inject material (though the salt might block any collision attack). But such a collision attack at best(from his point of view) allows the attacker to create an account for which he knows two different passwords. Not very useful...

Comment: Passwords _are_ vulnerable to hash _collsion_ attacks when using a hash with PAKE or augmented PAKE. $\;\;\;\;$ (In those cases, it is realistic that the adversary can inject the work factor(s) and the salt.) $\hspace{.7 in}$

Comment: Suppose the attacker has password1,password2,salt,workfactor[,memfactor] such that $\:$password1 $\neq$ password2$\:$ and $\:$passwordhash(workfactor,salt,password1[,memfactor]) = passwordhash(workfactor,salt,password2[,memfactor])$\:$. $\;\;$ If the inner PAKE is augmented, then the attacker computes a verifier for passwordhash(workfactor,salt,password2[,memfactor]). $\;\;$ When the client attempts to connect, the attacker sends it salt,workfactor[,memfactor] and then uses passwordhash(workfactor,salt,password2[,memfactor]) or the verifier as its input to the inner PAKE protocol. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Are bruteforce or rainbow tables really first preimage attacks?

Comment: @Smit Johnth: Yes, rainbow tables and password search by enumeration qualify as first-preimage attacks: they start from a hash, and try to find a value that hash to that; most usually, that's using brute-force.

Comment: I assumed first preimage is something that works with selected hash function and is faster than general purpose attacks like bruteforce or rainbow.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not. Since for finding message for a hash you don't find collision but a first preimage - which has quadratic complexity compared to collision attack due to birthday paradox.

Comment: The birthday paradox applies to brute-force collision search, not to collision finding by broken hash function. So hopefully MD5 is still secure (with more than only quadratic security) against preimage attacks. On the other hand, for preimage attacks against passwords a usually quite small search space applies, so its complexity is also smaller than a generic preimage search.

Comment: Duadratic security is more that enough :) Even MD4 which is completely unresistant to collisions is resistant to first and second preimages - at least, no successful attacks are known.

Comment: Yes, but there is no "quadratic" in there. It is not that a collision takes $x$ steps and a preimage takes $x^2$ steps, more like a collision takes $x$ steps (with a quite small $x$) and a preimage takes $x·2^{128}$ steps (or $x·N$, where $N$ is the number of passwords to check). The "quadratic" is only valid for a brute-force attack on unbroken hash algorithms.

Comment: Interesting. Can you provide real numbers for some hash functions?

Comment: Not really, sorry. As you said, MD4 is totally broken in terms of collision resistance, so much that building a collision takes even less work than one hash operation ($x$). On the other hand, to find a preimage, you still need a brute-force search of either around half of all possible preimages (for a short password), taking $N/2·x$ work, or in average $2^{127}$ hashes (for an preimage of an arbitrary hash), costing $2^{127}·x$ work, where $x$ is the cost of one hash evaluation. (Actually, if Wikipedia is correct, there is a faster preimage attack using $2^{102}$ work – I didn't check this.)